# How to make a Python mock derive from a base class?

Tags: python, c++, mocking, pybind11

I am implementing python bindings for some C++ code using pybind11. Now I am trying to write unit tests for the bindings.

There is a `class A` in C++ with constructor like this:

```
class A
{
    A(std::unique_ptr<B> B_ptr);
}
```

It accepts a `unique_ptr` to an object of `class B`. `class B` is an abstract base class which can be derived. I have written bindings such that `class B` can be derived from Python. Is it possible for a Python mock created using `unittest.mock` to derive from `class B` so that `A` will accept the mock in its constructor?

Answer (score 4):

Mocks can have a `spec` when defined, which they borrow their reported class from (along with many other basic behaviors). So the simplest way to do this is to do:

```py
mymock = Mock(spec=B())  # Mock borrows behaviors of this instance of B, including class
```

If you don't want to use `spec` (which has many other side-effects), you can perform a targeted modification of the reported class. [`Mock`s have an assignable `__class__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.__class__), so this will make an otherwise blank `Mock` that reports itself as a subclass of `B`:

```py
mymock = Mock()
mymock.__class__ = B
```

Comment: Actually this is not working, when this mock is sent to a C++ function, it is rejected due to not being B or derived from B.

Comment: @In78: That doesn't wholly surprise me; at the C extension layer, `pybind11` may be doing type-checking in ways that bypass `Mock`'s pseudo-class in favor of its real class. In that case, I think you're stuck, you'd just have to reimplement an actual subclass of `B` that has the mocked behavior you need, sorry.

Comment: Isn't there any mocking framework in python which allows the mock to derive from the mocked class? Like google mock works that way for C++.